# Does Catalyst 4500x-16s support 10/100 network devices?

Tags: cisco-catalyst, cisco-4500

Does 4500x-16s support 10/100 network devices? My vendor says that it is not able to and one of my devices can only support 10/100.

Comment: You can use the GLC-T or GLC-TE SFP in your switch which gives you 10/100/1000 cobber interface. You can see all supported SFP's here: [https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/interfaces_modules/transceiver_modules/compatibility/matrix/GE_Tx_Matrix.html#_Toc490141220](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/interfaces_modules/transceiver_modules/compatibility/matrix/GE_Tx_Matrix.html#_Toc490141220)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the GLC-T or GLC-TE SFP (1000BASE-T) in your switch which gives you 10/100/1000 copper interface. This SFP supports Category 5, 5e, 6, or 6a UTP/FTP copper cables.

You can see all supported SFP's for the Cisco 4500X here:

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/interfaces_modules/transceiver_modules/compatibility/matrix/GE_Tx_Matrix.html#_Toc490141220

Comment: Thanks. I'm confused with this statement on Cisco website which sounds contradictiory to me - _"When you install the GLC-T (1000Base-T) SFP transceiver,  10/100 Mbps with auto negotiation is not supported."_ [link](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst4500/release/note/ol-37xe-4500x.html).  Yet the feature list says _"Forced 10/100 Autonegotiation"_ is supported.  So does using the GLC-T SPF transceiver allow a 10/100 ethernet device to connect to the 4500X?  Btw, my 4500X only has fibre optics ports so my vendor used a small silver color adapter for my 10/100 device.

Comment: Wouldn't be the first time Cisco wrote something contradictory. Worked fine with 100 Mbit full duplex, tested yesterday.

Comment: May I know what version of IOS are you using?

Comment: @Joshua 3.8.4E MD

Answer (score 0):

Not likely. Cisco [list no 100 Mbit modules](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/switches/catalyst-4500x-16-sfp-switch/model.html).

Edit: the 1000BASE-T SFP should be able to link 10/100 Mbit/s.

Comment: Well while you are right about the modules that are not supported, the GLC-T SFP is still supported on the 4500X series, which gives the 10/100/1000 cobber capability. SFP+ is compatible with all normal SFP modules.

Comment: Doesn't the 1000BASE-T SFP support 10/100 Mbps?

Comment: @RonMaupin yay was faster than you!

Comment: @Cown, you need to teach Ron Trunk your trick :)

Comment: @RonMaupin ROFL

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Cisco - many other 1000BASE-T SFPs are not downward compatible.

Comment: @RonMaupin, 10/100 speeds with the 1000BASE-T SFPs are only supported on specific platforms. I am personally unsure about the 4500X platform.

Comment: @YLearn works fine, just tested.

Answer (score -1):

1000BASE-T SFP is recommended, which can well support both 10 and 100 Mbps

Comment: This answer has already be given by @Cown (but more detailed, and it was accepted). You should consider upvoting the existing answer rather than creating a not-this-good duplicate.